# Что происходит при перемещении объекта в самого себя?

Tags: c++, move

Допустим, у меня есть вектор, я его использую, а потом случайно перемещаю его не другому вектору, а себе же. Что в таком случае произойдёт? Ошибок не выдаёт. В векторе будет то же самое значение?

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main() {
  auto l = std::vector{1, 2, 3};
  auto I = std::vector{3, 2, 1};
  // ... 
  l = std::move(l); // ?
}
```

Comment: Зависит от компилятора. В G++ [очищается](https://ideone.com/V9tuGN), в VC++ остается нетронутым.

Comment: До C++23 — UB (на самом деле стандарт здесь не достаточно однозначен, и есть мнение, что это не UB, а unspecified behaviour). Начиная с C++23 неоднозначности устранены — вектор будет находиться в одном из корректных состояний, но в каком именно — не специфицируется. Подробнее см. [What does the standard library guarantee about self move assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13127455), [Self-move-assignment of library types, again](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2839).

Comment: @wololo А он и сейчас в корректном состоянии в обоих случаях :)

Comment: @Harry, я бы  сказал, что зависит от реализации оператора перемещения,  а не  компилятора.

Answer (score 0):

Вектор будет в валидном состоянии, но какое именно значение неизвестно. Это означает, что можно вызывать `empty` и `clear`, но не стоит получать значение какого-то элемента, пока не присвоишь ему новое. Смотрите https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move.